# Normalized random position generator

Tags: javascript, performance, random

I place various divs on screen by adding random x and y positions successively normalized with this function. My question is, how well is it written? Can I improve it? If so, then how?

I am worried not only about the coding style but also performance since I'm using multiple `Math.random()`s.

```
   function normalize(n) {
        var x = 0, i = 0;
        while (i < n) {
            x += Math.random();
            i++;
        }
        return (x / n);
    }
```

Comment: What values of `n` do you intend to use? 5? 100?

Comment: @200_success 0 to 20

Answer (score 2):

With totally zero context of what's going on and I'm not a math person, why "normalize"? What does "normalize" mean? As a front-end developer, [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) comes into mind, but it's not related to CSS. So I'm clueless. If you can give a better name, that would be great.

Also, a more compact way to write this is using a `for` loop

```
function normalize(n) {
  for(var x = 0, i = 0; i < n; i++){
    x += Math.random();
  }
  return (x / n);
}
```

Comment: it normalizes the range of possible output values into the interval of [0, 1) (the same interval of the return values from `Math.random()`, see my answer for the math in all its g(l)ory.

Answer (score 2):

> I place various divs on screen by adding random x and y positions successively normalized with this function.

This is a rather vague requirement, yet the resulting code is quite specific.

> I am worried not only about the coding style but also performance since I'm using multiple `Math.random()`s.

I am worried about if the generated output is actually the desired one. (Are you aware of what this function does?)

### What's going on

Let's start by recaping what [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) does by quoting MDN:

> The `Math.random()` function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range **[0, 1)**

Basically speaking, that means it's uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 with every value in between equally likely.

Now what happens if you add multiple such uniformly distributed variables together as you do with variable `x`?

[Figure 7.6 of this pdf from Section 7.2 (page 15 in the pdf, page 299 in the document)](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Echance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf) shows the density function of the sum of n such random variables:

> [image: convolution of distributions]

The X-axis shows what values are possible and the Y-axis shows how the probability is to get this value.<sup>1</sup>

For `n=2`, most values that you get for `x` will be around 1. For `n=4`, the peak is at 2. In general (as you can see from the picture, the peak is at `n/2`. Again, for `n=1`, you get a uniform distribution with everything in [0, 1) equally likely. I added the density for `n=1` to the plot in blue color:

[image: added n=1]

On top of that, you do the normalisation of `(x / n)`, which squishes all the curves in the plot into the interval [0, 1) on the X-axis and does indeed normalise the range of possible values. I allowed myself to retrace two of the plots:

[image: marked plots]

and to normalize them by scaling each one into the interval [0, 1):

[image: normalized plots]

ignoring my mad image editing skills, it looks like both plots are pretty similar now. They both have the peak in the middle. Sure, the first one has a higher peak, but that doesn't make them much different: both probabilities will produce values near their peak with a higher likelyhood, which is in the middle for both of them.

So far it looks like the several calls to `Math.random()` create very similarly distributed random variables.

### A practical demonstration

I created the above plots for all n up to 10 with this piece of octave code:

```
max = 10;
plots = [];

for n = 1:max

    r = zeros(1000000,1);
    
    for i = 1:n
        r += rand(1000000, 1) * 1000;
    endfor
    
    r /= n;
    
    y = zeros(1000,1);
    for random = r'
        y(ceil(random)) += 1;
    endfor
    
    plots = [plots y/n];
    
endfor
```

I work in the interval up to 1000, but qualitatively, the plots that `plot(plots)` yields are the same as what you see in the plot above:

[image: n up to 10 probabilities]

> What values of n do you intend to use? 5? 100? – 200_success♦
>
> @200_success 0 to 20 – Asperger

I wouldn't go as far to say it doesn't make a difference what value `n` has, but considering how little the distribution changes for the cost of another call to `Math.random()`, I don't think it's worth it.

The parameter `n` is also kind of meaningless. I say it's impossible to predict a certain outcome given a certain value for it. It's more like a knob that has to be adjusted by trial and error until desirable values are obtained.

### summary, tl, dr;

- The function does indeed normalize the range of values into [0, 1)
- The parameter has not a significant influence on the shape probability density function that's used to create the values (this could be desired behaviour)
- There's no meaningful way to influence the probability density function. A normal distribution for example is defined by how thick (or thin) the bell shape is.

---

<sup>1</sup> Strictly mathematically speaking, this is horribly wrong. But for the intuitive understanding, it's perfect. Sorry math nerds.